# How can I change the font for my auto-email's text?

Tags: java, email

I have a program which has to send email every day to the same addresses.  I use packages like `javax.mail.*` and `it.sauronsoftware.cron4j.Scheduler`.  It works fine, but I do not know how to change the font of the text in email (for example, output some information in bigger font, or bold, or underlined).

I store the email text in a `String` variable.  And I tried to type something like this:

`content = "Some text <b>bold part</b> ... continue"`

... but unfortunately, it did not work and in the received mail I have the same string with `<b>` tags.

How can I manipulate the font for my email text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be sending the mail as a plain-text email, not as an HTML mail (which you need if you want to use text formatting). [See this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm).

The most important difference is that you need to specify `text/html` as the mail's MIME type

```
message.setContent("Some text <b>bold part</b> ... continue", "text/html");
```

Some mail clients also interpret a few plain-text commands such as `"Some text *bold part* ... continue"`, but I wouldn't rely on that.